# How to use related model attribute as nameFrom value in relation form widget in OctoberCMS

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

In my plugin I have two models:

- Manager
- Office

In office model I have relation:

```
public $hasMany = [
    'managers'  => [Manager::class, 'key' => 'office_id'],
];
```

Each manager belong to some office and related to backend user:

```
public $belongsTo = [
    'backend_user' => [BackendUser::class],
    'office' => [Office::class]
];
```

In Office form I have relation widget and want to use full name as nameFrom value:

```
fields:
    managers:
        type: relation
        label: Managers
        nameFrom: full_name
```

But full name (fisrt name and last name) is stored in backend user:

```
$first_name = $manager->backend_user->first_name;
$last_name = $manager->backend_user->last_name;
```

The idea was to create a mutator in manager model:

```
public function getFullNameAttribute() 
{
    return $this->backend_user->first_name.' '.$this->backend_user->last_name;
}
```

But in this case name gets from first model, not from each, and I got all checkboxes with same name.

How can I achive that?

Answer (score 0):

Use select:

```
fields:
    managers:
        type: relation
        label: Managers
        select: concat(first_name,' ',last_name)
```

This will work with a bunch of the available MySQL aggregates.

https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#widget-relation

Comment: first_name, last_name stored not in manager model, but in backend_user, manager model contain only id of backend user

Comment: You could use a hasManyThrough relation to return the correct table.